# Find a for which H=[0,1] is a stable part of R in relation to a given algebric operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How does one find $a$ for which $h=[0,1]$ is a stable part of $R$ in relation to the following algebric operation:
$$x*y = x+y-xy-ax-ay+a$$

Comment: I tried using the fact that, for any x,y in H, x*y must be in H, but I didn't get far with that.

Comment: So, you haven't tried plugging values in for $a$?!??

Comment: That I have not tried